# Custom post using angular rails resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Hi I'm using rails and angularjs with the angularrailsresource gem. I need to do a custom post request to a rails resource I have defined called 'Comment'. I tried using the $post method like this:

```
  Comment.$post('some_method', {comment_id: comment.id, username: username, type: 'mention'}).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
  });
```

and it makes a request but it always makes it under the root of the page I'm on. So I want to make a request to '/comments/', but it tries to make a request to '/patients/some_method' and if I do this:

```
  Comment.$post('comments/do_stuff', {comment_id: comment.id, username: username, type: 'mention'}).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
  });
```

it will try to post to 'patients/comments/some_method', or whatever else the root of the page I'm on is. Is there a way to tell it to post directly to the resource and not through the the url context that I am currently on? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the path with a `/` before it, otherwise it will trigger the action using the relative path. Try this:

```
Comment.$post('/comments/do_stuff' ....
```

Notice the `/` before `comments`.